Hipfire calculations when shooting, calculating a random raycast direction inside the crosshair
Update: I finally solved the issue, note that I didn't work at this 100%, that's why I found a solution after so much time.
I am facing this issue from a few days, I want to shoot a Raycast inside the UI reticle but I can't get it working as it should, changing the screen aspect ratio or the reticle size is enough to make the bullet go outside the reticle, for example setting the resolution to 4K is going to make the bullet hit almost the center of the reticle.
Here is the code responsible for handling the raycast:
//If you scroll below this html page, you can see the implementation of the UIHandler methods with comments
Vector3 origin = UIHandler.SINGLETON.gunCrosshair.GetCrosshairPosition();
float pixelDelta = UIHandler.SINGLETON.gunCrosshair.GetCrosshairPixelDelta();
float spread = pixelDelta / Screen.width * Camera.main.fieldOfView;
/* hipfireSpreadMultiplier is a value needed because the spread itself is a very small value.
   I am adding to the origin just the right direction for testing */
origin += spread* Vector3.right * hipfireSpreadMultiplier;
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(origin);
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit raycastHit, 900, enemyLayerMask))
   Debug.Log("I did hit " + raycastHit.transform.name);

And here is the code responsible for handling the UI reticle:
public void UpdateCrosshairSize(float size)
{
    //This method makes the crosshair larger when moving
    crosshair.sizeDelta = Vector2.one * size * crosshairSizeMultiplier;
}
public float GetCrosshairInnerEdge()
{
    //right is a RectTransform, it is the right white line of the crosshair
    return right.position.x - right.sizeDelta.x / 2;
}
public Vector3 GetCrosshairPosition()
{
    //crosshair is a RectTransform, parent of all the lines of the reticle
    return crosshair.position;
}
public float GetCrosshairPixelDelta()
{
    //This calculates the difference between the position of the crosshair and the start of the right reticle line
    return GetCrosshairInnerEdge() - GetCrosshairPosition().x;
}

Even if the code seems right the bullet doesn't always match the crosshair.
Below you can see the images showing the issue, the size is less than 20kb each so it's mobile data friendly. All the screenshots are made by keeping the camera stright forward.
Note that the gun moves up due to recoil but only the crosshair delta is used in the spread calculation.
In particular when firing the first shot the bullet matches the crosshair:

When firing the second shot the bullet touches the right line of the crosshair:

When firing the third shot  the bullet goes outside the crosshair:

I have tried to:

In the spread calculation:

Multiply by the CrosshairSize instead of the hipfireSpreadMultiplier
Remove the Screen.width divider


Raycast using the original spread instead of calculating the reticle one


If you remove the randomness, will bullets go to the center of the crosshair?

Yes, without the randomness it will use just virtualCamera.forward and it will hit the center.

As always it turns out that the easiest solution is the one working.
I did add to the right line of the reticle an empty gameobject which is anchored to the inner edge of the right line as you can see (33Kb image):

I edited the raycast calculation code as it follows:
float maxSpread = UIHandler.SINGLETON.gunCrosshair.GetCrosshairInnerEdgePosition().x - UIHandler.SINGLETON.gunCrosshair.GetCrosshairPosition().x;
Vector3 randomSpread = Vector3.up * Random.Range(-maxSpread, maxSpread) + Vector3.right * Random.Range(-maxSpread, maxSpread);
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(UIHandler.SINGLETON.gunCrosshair.GetCrosshairPosition() + randomSpread);

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit raycastHit, 900, weaponData.enemyLayerMask))
   Debug.Log("I did hit " + raycastHit.transform.name);

And I refactored the UI code:
public Vector3 GetCrosshairInnerEdgePosition()
{
    //You shouldn't use Find at runtime! Use a reference or you are going to waste performance.
    return right.Find("InnerEdge").position;
}
public Vector3 GetCrosshairPosition()
{
    return crosshair.position;
}

And that's enough to make all work, I feel so dumb, the solution was extremely easy and probably more efficient than calculating the pixel delta based on the Screen.width at runtime.

I can think of two ways to do this accurately.
I suppose you could base it off of visual angle:
The distance from the center to the crosshair edge, in pixels, as a percentage of the width of the screen, multiplied by your players FOV, should give you the spread rotation in degrees.
float pixelDelta = crosshairEdge.x - crosshairCenter.x;
float spreadAngle = (pixelDelta/(float)Screen.width) * Camera.main.fieldOfView;

And then you'd have to do some funky Quaternion math to rotate the virtualCamera.forward vector by that angle in a random direction, using Quaterion.AngleAxis, that many degrees around an arbitrary Random.InsideUnitSphere angle. Something like this, although I haven't tested it:
Quaterion lookDir = Quaternion.Euler(virtualCamera.forward);
Quaternion randomDir = Quaterinion.Euler(Random.insideUnitSphere);
Vector3 shotDir = Quaternion.RotateTowards(lookDir, randomDir, spreadAngle).eulerAngles;

Note that this would also work backwards, where you could generate the distance that the UI elements need to be from the center by calculating the maximum visual angle that the bullets will deviate from the lookDir using your current method.
Alternatively, you could stick to your Camera-first method.
Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay should definitely work for this use case. Make sure that you're inputting the right parameters. If that doesn't work, you could use Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint, although that implementation is less clean for this use case, seeing as you'd need to specify some arbitrary z depth from the camera.

Thank you for the detailed answer spacemann, I will try the solution later and mark it as answer if it works.

I did try it the Quaternion hell solution, it does fire some shots fine whilst some shotDirections are pointing straight up.

I updated the original question, I am trying to figure out a way to make this work.
